# ExtJS 4 store callback function don't get record

Tags: extjs, callback, extjs4, store

**Store callback as follows:**

```
var store = new Ext.create("Ext.data.TreeStore", {
    model: "DeptModel",
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'jsonWebCommMenuOp_getMenus?PID=0',
        reader: 'json'
    },
    autoload: true
});

store.load({
    callback: function(records, options, success) {
        var jsonStr = Ext.JSON.encode(records[0].raw);
        var jsonObj = Ext.JSON.decode(jsonStr);
        alert(jsonStr);
    }
});
```

**Server response as follows:**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "msg": "123"
}
```

I test callback param `success`, it is equals to **`true`** but **`records`** is blank [].

What's the reason? Please help me.

Comment: Where is your `DeptModel` ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have to consider following things:

- What really is your server response. If it is `{"success":true, "msg":"123"}`, then you really miss data.
- You must set the name of the property which contains the data items in `reader` config. In ExtJS 4 this can be done with `root`, in EXTJS 5,6 with `rootProperty`.
- If you load store data by code, set `autoLoad` to `false`.

ExtJS 4.2

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'data'
}
```

ExtJS 5 and ExtJS 6

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    rootProperty: 'data'
}
```

Notes:

I've reproduced your test case with EXTJS 4.2 and these are the reasons for such a behavior:

- JSON response not contains data
- `root` (`rootProperty`) config is not set.
- JSON response contains data, but the name of the property which contains this data is not the same as in `reader` config.

Working example:

Server response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {"text": "Some words"},
        {"text": "Some words"},
        {"text":"Some words"}
    ]
}
```

HTML:

```
Ext.define('DeptModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'text', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var store = new Ext.create("Ext.data.TreeStore", {
        model: "DeptModel",
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            //url: 'jsonWebCommMenuOp_getMenus?PID=0',
            // I've used simple PHP script to populate JSON response:
            url: 'store-load.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data'
            }   
        },
        autoLoad: false
    });

    store.load(
    {
        callback: function(records, options, success)
        {
            //var jsonStr = Ext.JSON.encode(records[0].raw);
            //var jsonObj = Ext.JSON.decode(jsonStr);
            //alert(jsonStr);
            console.log(records);
        }
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some points below which are you need to recheck with your code:-

1. `autoLoad` instead of `autoload`.
2. With `TreeStore` you should mention `root: {}`

Have a look at this [**working fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2j70).

**Note:** I am using `data.json` to request.

Hope this will help/guide you properly.